# Divide a floating point number into discrete segments

Tags: numbers, rounding, floating

I need to create a program which will divide a floating point number into discrete pieces .
I need to go from start_actual (5.66882) to end_actual (8.05153) in increments of increment 0.43322 , in case while incrementing the value overshoots end_actual it is reduced down to end_actual and the process terminates.

Here is my attempt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    float max=9.5678;
    float min= 5.2356;
    float diff=max-min;

    float start= 10; //percentages
    float end= 65; //percentages
    float incr= 10; //percentages

    int steps= ((end-start)/incr);

    float start_actual= min+ (diff*start/100);
    float end_actual= max-(diff*(100-end)/100);
    float incr_actual= diff*incr/100;

    cout<<"Min value is "<<min<<endl;
    cout<<"Max value is "<<max<<endl;

    cout<<"start_actual is "<<start_actual<<endl;
    cout<<"end_actual is "<<end_actual<<endl;
    cout<<"increment is"<<incr_actual<<endl;
    cout<<"steps is"<<steps<<endl;


    float value;
    steps=steps+1;

    for(int i=0;i<=steps;i++)
    {

        value= start_actual + (incr_actual*i);


        if(value<=end_actual)
        cout<<"value is "<<value<<endl;

        else if ((end_actual-value)<incr_actual)
        {
            value=end_actual;
            cout<<"final value is "<<value;
            break;
        }

        //else if (((value-end_actual)<0.1 )||((-value+end_actual)<0.1 ))
        //cout<<"value is"<<end_actual<<endl;

    }


    //cout<<"diiff "<<diff<<endl;


    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

in this case the result is
5.66882
6.10204
6.53526
6.96848

....etc..
8.05153

but if i change the value of

```
    float start= 10; //percentages
    float end= 65; //percentages
    float incr= 5; //percentages
```

the last value is printed twice (8.05153) because of round-off errors , how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance..
Vipin

Comment: How do you mean "printed twice"? You're not using a loop to print. Also, it's not quite clear what the issue is. Floating point values have limited accuracy and you should account for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing equality of floating point numbers, which is *extremely* error prone.
 `(value-end_actual)<0.1 )` is not actually comparing the result of `(value-end_actual)` with `0.1`. `0.1` is some arbitrary number, maybe something like `0.100000000000000005`. What this means is that floating point comparisons cannot be treated as decimal comparisons. What you need is an "almost comparison" with some type of designated precision. You would of course implement such behavior as a function looking something like this:

```
template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
inline 
bool AlmostEqual(T lhs, T rhs, std::size_t precision  = 100000)
{
    return (std::abs(a - b) < 1.0 / precision); 
}
```